# SFML renderTexture : flipped output

Tags: shader, sfml, render-to-texture

I'm using SFML to render effects using shaders. I use sf::RenderTexture objects to render my effect, and then use a RenderWindow to display it.

When i render 2 effects using the output of the first as the input of the second, the displayed image is flipped.

For example, the code below displays the input image upwards down, and i don't understand why. I use the shader file given in the SFML documentation [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-shader.php) (that i also copied at the end of the question).

If you replace l.33 with l.34 (which is commented) or l.42 with l.43, the result is normal. Copying the output texture seems to solve the problem.

Why copying the output texture of a renderTexture solves the problem? Also, i would like to avoid copying textures, is there any other solution?

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Loading image
    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromFile("lena.png");
    int s_x = tex.getSize().x;
    int s_y = tex.getSize().y;

    //loading shader;
    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile("shader.frag",sf::Shader::Fragment);

    //Creating drawable object (rectangle) to be drawn by renderTextures
    sf::VertexArray rect(sf::Quads,4);
    rect[0].position = sf::Vector2f(0,0);
    rect[1].position = sf::Vector2f(0,s_y);
    rect[2].position = sf::Vector2f(s_x,s_y);
    rect[3].position = sf::Vector2f(s_x,0);
    rect[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(0.0,0.0);
    rect[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(0.0,1.0);
    rect[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(1.0,1.0);
    rect[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(1.0,0.0);

    //Render with the loaded image
    shader.setParameter("texture", tex);
    sf::RenderTexture renderTexture;
    renderTexture.create(s_x,s_y);
    renderTexture.clear();
    renderTexture.draw(rect, &shader);
    renderTexture.display();

    //Rendering with the output from the first render
    const sf::Texture& tex2 = renderTexture.getTexture();
    //switching those lines displays a correct image
    //sf::Texture tex2 = renderTexture.getTexture();
    shader.setParameter("texture", tex2);
    sf::RenderTexture renderTexture2;
    renderTexture2.create(s_x,s_y);
    renderTexture2.clear();
    renderTexture2.draw(rect, &shader);
    renderTexture2.display();

    //displaying
    const sf::Texture& tex3 = renderTexture2.getTexture();
    //switching those lines displays a correct image
    //sf::Texture tex3 = renderTexture2.getTexture();
    sf::Sprite sprite(tex3);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(s_x,s_y), "");
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();

    char c;
    std::cin>>c;

    return 0;
}
```

shader.frag

```cpp
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    // lookup the pixel in the texture
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    // multiply it by the color
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color * pixel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem when using shaders a while ago:
http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11178.msg77236

The texture coordinates are inverted because the texture produced by sf::RenderTexture is inverted (because of FBO).

The behaviour is consistent, so you can work around it and consider the coordinates to be inverted when working with RenderTextures.

Comment: It is more specifically because OpenGL's default coordinate system has the lower-left as the origin, and SFML has upper-left as the origin (it does the appropriate work to make normal shape drawing use the upper-left as the origin, but doesn't do similar work for "render textures"). Yet another person with this problem, but with raw OpenGL - http://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=8966